# Able to setup credit card as a backup source if checking account charge fails?

Tags: balanced-payments

I'd like customers to submit checking account and credit card information. Is it possible that if a checking account charge fails, that a credit card is charged automatically? Is it possible to have multiple credit cards as backup?  I understand the charge for a failed checking account charge is $3.50, how is this similar or different to an NSF fee that a bank would charge?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you can’t charge (debit) a checking account through Balanced (except of your company’s own account). You can charge credit cards, and make deposits to checking accounts. You could have your customers provide multiple cards as back-ups, but you need to explicitly handle the logic for charging the back-up cards yourself. Balanced’s fees (outside the basic rates) are just those passed through from our bank. Cheers.